# What kind of Huffy is it?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: stripped down Huffy frame]

Before it got taken apart and striped down it said HUFFY. Trying to find out what kind/year, thinking of making a custom with it.

Comment: Not sure why you care.  You can guestimate the age based on the features it has (eg, appears to be a threadless headset), but knowing the precise age will not really do anything for you (or the bike).  It's just a Huffy.

Answer (score 3):

Just stop at Huffy.

If you must, look for a serial number on the bottom bracket (not sure if Huffys have one or not) and call them. I'm not sure what knowing what kind of Huffy it is is going to buy you, though. The parts that are missing should be readily available- or at least orderable- from your LBS.

Comment: Rebuilding the bike with parts from the LBS will certainly cost more than a complete bike.